# Core Data Custom Transformable Object Class Array

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsobject, nscoding

**IMPORTANT**

I have learned that what I was doing below wasn't the smartest solution to my problem. I am curious to see the solution to my question, but for now I was able to accomplish my goal by using Core Data one to many relationships instead, which works!

**ORIGINAL POST**

I have a Core Data entity called `TestPeriods` and I want it to have an attribute called `periods`, which is Transformable, and is made of an array of a custom class called `PeriodClass`

To sum up the problem, something is going wrong when I try accessing the periods saved in my entity as you will see by the end.

Here is my entity extension

```
extension TestPeriods {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<TestPeriods> {
    return NSFetchRequest<TestPeriods>(entityName: "TestPeriods")
}

@NSManaged public var periods: [PeriodClass]?

}
```

Here is the `PeriodClass` with a start, end, and period

```
public class PeriodClass: NSObject, NSCoding {


var start: Date?
var end: Date?
var period: Int16?

public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(start, forKey: "start")
    aCoder.encode(end, forKey: "end")
    aCoder.encode(period, forKey: "period")
}


public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    start = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "start") as! Date
    end = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "end") as! Date
    period = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "period") as! Int16
}


init(start: Date, end: Date, period: Int16) {
    super.init()
    self.start = start
    self.end = end
    self.period = period
}

}
```

Here is how I am saving to the `TestPeriods` entity

```
let container = TestPeriods(context: PersistenceServce.context)
// The 'period' I refer to below is just an object with the same start, end, and period and I know is not nil
let x = PeriodClass(start: period.start!, end: period.end!, period: period.period)
container.periods?.append(x)

// Saving the object here
PersistenceServce.saveContext()
// I know this Persistence Service is not a problem as I use it for other Core Data Objects
```

The problem is when I try retrieving the `PeriodClass` array

```
let tFetch: NSFetchRequest<TestPeriods> = TestPeriods.fetchRequest()
    do {
        let classes = try PersistenceServce.context.fetch(tFetch)
        print("TEST CLASS COUNT \(classes.count)")
        ...
    }
```

Here, it prints `1` since I previously saved one entity with multiple periods

However, when I call

```
print("TEST CLASS PERIODS \(classes[0].periods)")
```

All I get is nil

For some reason, it is saving the entity, but not properly saving the periods that are supposed to go along with it. Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how to fix this problem. Thanks!

Comment: What is the reason **not** to use another entity for `PeriodClass`? And why are all properties optional although they are clearly decoded with non-optional values?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `container.periods` is nil, so the line:

```
container.periods?.append(x)
```

does nothing.  You need to initialise `periods` to an empty array before you can append items to it.  Or for the first item, just create an an array with that item in it:

```
container.periods = [x]
```

Comment: Okay, I will try that. I will let you know if that works! Thank you so much